# Why are my asynchronously retrieved data only appearing after I click (Vue)

Tags: asynchronous, vue.js, promise

I have an input with an @change event:

```
        <f7-searchbar
        :clear-button="true"
        @focus="showFilters=true"
        @blur="showFilters=false"
        v-model="searchText"
        @change="handleSearch"
        >
```

This is meant to get search results from a database and display them in a table.

The method to get the results:

```
 handleSearch: function(){
     var preResults = []
     var postResults         
     var self=this
     var vals
     db.query('categories/search', {reduce: false}).then(function (res) {
     console.log(res['rows'][0]['key'] + ' is the result of searched')       
     vals = res['rows']
     }).then(function(){
     self.searchResults = vals.map(row => {
         return row['key']['metadata']
     })

     })
 },
```

Which should be displayed in this table:

```
            <table>
                <tr v-for="entry in searchResults" class="popup-trigger" style="text-align: left;">
                       <span>{{ entry }}</span>
                </tr>                   
            </table>
```

I am expecting these results to update when searchText changes.  But that doesn't happen.  The results display only after I enter something into the search, and then click where the table should be displayed.  I have no idea why clicking should update it.  Can anyone help me understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **@input** event instead of **@change** event

Also my suggestion is to not send request for every character, for example if you want to search *apple*, and type fast:

```
a - send request
p - send request
p - send request
l - send request
e - send request
```

You can use timer to check if user stoped with typing

```
<input @input="userStopTyping" 

  userStopTyping () {
    if (this.timer) {
      clearTimeout(this.timer)
    }

    this.timer = setTimeout(this.yourFunction, 200)
  }
```

So if you type fast apple, you will send only one request.